# Formatting using FormatDateTime for running SQL Query in MS Access

Tags: date, ms-access, vba

I have dates in `TakeDate` Field (Data type : Date ) in a table of MS Access.
I have a text Box `txtGdateTo` in a search form with `Format` set to `Short Date`

> When I run SQL queries like as below, I don't get desired data filtered.

```
Select * from tblWork WHERE TakeDate <= Me.txtGdateTo
```

Hence I tried the below SQL, but it does not work too.

```
Select * from tblWork WHERE TakeDate <= Format(Me.txtGdateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

I added another filed to the table `TakeDate0` with function

`TakeDate0: FormatDateTime([TakeDate],"\#mm/dd/yyyy\#")`

This gives me value as `#error`.

> Q : Is there any best way to manage these errors using date field?
>
> Q : What formatting needs to be done and is there a need for the additional column?

In my case, the users will enter data in the table in the format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FormatDateTime-Function-aef62949-f957-4ba4-94ff-ace14be4f1ca - function reference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After researching for about 2 hours and some hints from @Gustav answers, I was able to figure out the solution to the problem.

> 1st - Use function `FormatDateTime` and not `Format`

```
Select * from tblWork WHERE TakeDate <= #" & FormatDateTime(Me.txtTdateTo, 2) & "#"
```

> 2nd - Make sure the format is correct

`txtGdateTo` in a search form, `Format` set to `Short Date`

> 3rd - No need for another column for searching functionality.

Comment: Sorry, but `FormatDateTime` is intended for other purposes and not like here where it will be doomed to fail in a non-English environment, because the parameter "2" (vbShortDate) will produce a localized string expression for the date, while what you need is a non-localized unambiguous format understood by Access SQL, like the ISO sequence: _yyyy-mm-dd_.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. All my users will be English based. I know this for sure. Will it still be wrong way to use?

Answer (score 1):

*Me* can't be used in a query. So try:

```
Select * From tblWork Where TakeDate <= Format(Forms!YourForm!txtGdateTo, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

In VBA you must format the *string expression* of the date before concatenating, like:

```
SQL = "Select * From tblWork Where TakeDate <= #" & Format(Me!txtGdateTo.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```

Comment: I am constructing the SQL query in a string and then assigning the string to the Row source of list box

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was using the function incorrectly. The correct way is mentioned in the answer by me.